# Pixilation and distortion seems to have recently appeared in a HP Pavilion camera

Tags: windows-10, hp-pavilion

While recording video with HP Pavilion camera after latest Window 10 Update I found that the video is blurred and contains distortions. Looks like a low light photo even in bright light.

I have no idea what might have caused this since I have been using the camera for web conferencing and the result was never this bad.

What could cause this issue? How can I fix this?

[image]

---

Had chat with HP assistant

First they suggested to delete the camera from the device management and restart the PC. That did not work at all.

I had to contact them again and they told to run following script with admin privileges.

```
sfc /scannow
```

Once the `sfc /cannow` is complete please paste this script: `chkdsk C: /f /r /x`

Press Y when prompted.

Once that is done run

```
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

Wait for it to complete. Then Uninstall the camera driver from device manager and install the drivers using HP recovery manager.

If more than one webcam driver is listed, right-click the driver and select uninstall for any driver that is not the HP Webcam-101 or Microsoft USB Video Device driver. Once the other drivers have been removed.Perform Clean boot Right-click the Start button. Click Search. Type msconfig and hit Enter on your keyboard. Click Services. Click the checkbox next to Hide all Microsoft services. Click Disable all. Click Ok and Apply Restart device.

Once booted up, open your camera software. To check if the issue is resolved or still persisted.

When all is said and done, it took almost 1 or 2 hours performing all disk check etc... But the issue still persists. No improvements.

Comment: Honestly, it just appears to be a low-quality image.  I assume this behavior is actually new, and prior to the update, the image wasn't like this?  Have you uninstalled the update in question?

Comment: No, I am not sure it is due to the update. I have been using the camera for web conferencing and the result was never this bad.

Comment: I also updated BIOS recently. Could that cause the issue?

Comment: No; That would be very unlikely.  Have you tried to uninstall any recent driver updates and or Windows updates?